asset not showing in flutter flame web and android
I have faced this isse multiple times in web, now it occurs in flame kit also.
I am not able to display image with any means possible.
Code snippet where image is used
Import statements
output where is image not displaying
I am trying to render image in flame kit but it shows image not visible

DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? Please [edit] your question to include the text.
